# iphone screen - type of view to use

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

looking for some advice on what type of view can be used to build a screen with the following elements:

2 labels followed by 2 buttons.
Then a small table view with 3 rows.

Should a UIView be used or a UITableView?
I've attempted using a UITableView - however I couldn't add the labels or buttons.

So I've now built the view using a UIView. I added the labels and buttons and then a UITableView from the library. However I have no idea how to populate the rows in the table?

Any ideas?

Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always create the view that you want and return it in the [table view delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)'s [`-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method. That would give you your table view rows that you want plus your custom view above it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use the UITableView before going any further. Time taken now will pay off later on.

There are [plenty of tutorials about the UITableView](https://www.google.com/search?q=uitableview+tutorial), but I found the best learning I had was from the free [iTunes U Standford iPhone course](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225). You don't need to watch it all, but at the very least you should watch the episode on UITableView, as it'll cover everything you need to know. I strongly recommend watching it all, especially the first 8 or so lectures, as it covers the basics of what you need to know really, really effectively.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have actually viewed some of these tutorials and found them useful.. I think its time to review them again.